# Is it possible to testing uitest (XCUI) when open url external browser?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, testing, xcuitest

Currently, I have to create automation ui test with XCUI and I have some action to open external browser by default is Safari.

I need to create some uitest's behavior like this.

1. Go to external browser when click my button.
2. Check is open correct url in browser (or just open browser) ?
3. Go back to our app with resume state.

Is it impossible to do that ?.

Comment: I don't think you need to test that it would actually open external app, because that's not something you can control from your app. However, you can test that `UIApplication.canOpenUrl()` or `UIApplication.open(...)` is fired using a protocol abstraction.

Comment: Thank you for your comment @Ben but my quality assurance need it. T_T

Comment: What I mean is that testing opening a web url on iOS properly open Safari with the matching url would be a test for Safari development team. That's why I mentioned using a protocol with `open()` and `canOpenUrl()` to fill the gap, assuming Safari will always behave as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Absolutely. Safari is an XCUIApplication just like any other with a bundle identifier of `com.apple.mobilesafari`.

To check the URL you'll `tap()` the `URL` field (it's a button when a page loads) and read the value of the `URL` field (at this point it's a textField). Once you're done asserting that, `activate()` your app and you'll be back in it (note: my tests finish after asserting so I don't have to do this, but it's the published method - you could always enter debug and find how to tap the button to return to your application in the top-left of the screen if this doesn't work).

I'm happy to provide exact code if you show me you've tried this and can't get it working, but it's pretty straightforward XCUI automation.

Comment: As a followup to this, I was finding that this to be a bit flaky. XCUITest would sometimes work so quickly it would attempt to read the URL before the page was loaded (I may or may not have been dealing with redirects - can't remember). To solve this I set up a wait/timer to expire when a % sign was no longer found in the URL button's `otherElements.firstMatch` (it's a loading indicator hidden in the accessibility).

Comment: We've recently started using inline browsers in our app, which don't have a URL bar so this solution does not work. I'll provide a new answer.

Answer (score 4):

Providing the exact code, that worked for me

```
     enum SafariError: Error {
          case appLoadTimeout
     }
    
    let safari = XCUIApplication(bundleIdentifier: "com.apple.mobilesafari")
    app.buttons["MyButtom"].tap() // MyButton launches Safari
    
    guard safari.wait(for: .runningForeground, timeout: 5) else {
        throw SafariError.appLoadTimeout
    }
    
    safari.otherElements["Address"].tap()
    XCTAssertEqual(safari.textFields["Address"].value  as! String, "https://check-url.com")

    app.activate() //Back to my app
```

Comment: How are you accounting for a slow loading page? 50% of the time I've found processing to occur too quickly after Safari is running in the foreground for the address to contain what I'm expecting. I have two solutions to this, but curious how you're doing it or if it's not been a problem for you.

Comment: It hasn't been an issue for me, the test passes successfully, I think maybe that's why I added a wait method to Safari

Answer (score 0):

The previous answers work fine for an external browser. If you app happens to launch inline browsers, they won't work as there is no URL bar. You could detect the inline browser and tap the Safari button to launch it externally before checking the URL, but then you'd have to reactivate your app and close the inline browser. Many more steps.

THERE IS AN EASIER WAY THAT WILL WORK WITH BOTH BROWSER TYPES!

What do these browsers share? A share button! How can we get the URL from there? `Copy` will place the URL in the pasteboard, which we have access to.

```
 app.buttons["ShareButton"].tap()
 _ = copyButton.waitForExistence(timeout: Waits.short.rawValue) // a tiny wait is necessary here for the share page to open fully
 app.buttons["Copy"].tap()
 let URL = UIPasteboard.general.string!
```

There are two catches here:

1. When inline, `app` is your app. When external, it's `com.apple.mobilesafari`. You'll have to have logic to handle that.
2. You want to wait for the page to finish loading. By not doing so, you will run into flakiness. When the page is loading, there is a `ReloadButton`. When that goes away, you should expect to see a `StopButton`. If the reload button doesn't disappear, the page isn't loading completely so you may need to hit the stop button, but do so in a safe way as I have seen maybe 1% of the time the page load completes in the milliseconds between giving up on it and performing that tap - I do a quick `isHittable` check before tapping.

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve this by capturing the Safari app and validating your URL in its address bar in two steps. Assuming the tested URL is `https://myapp.com/something`, here is how to test if it's opened inside Safari:

```swift
        let safari = XCUIApplication(bundleIdentifier: "com.apple.mobilesafari")
        guard safari.wait(for: .runningForeground, timeout: 10) else {
            XCTFail("could not open Safari")
            return
        }
        // we use CONTAINS because at first, only the base URL is displayed inside the text field. For example, if the URL is https://myapp.com/something, the value of the address bar would be 'myapp.com'
        let pred = NSPredicate(format: "value CONTAINS[cd] %@", "myapp.com")
        let addressBar = safari.textFields.element(matching: pred)
        // tap is needed to reveal the full URL string inside the address bar
        addressBar.tap()
        
        let textField = safari.textFields.element(matching: pred)
        XCTAssertEqual(textField.value as? String, "https://myapp.com/something")
```

What happens here is that, as soon as the app opens the link inside Safari, it tries to read the target URL from the address bar, tap on it in order to be able to read its text field content, and finally asserts the expected URL string against the value of the address bar.

This approach is more stable as it directly checks the value of all the text fields inside the browser instead of referring to their `identifier`s, for example, checking the "Address" identifier won't work today as it no longer exists in the Safari view hierarchy.

Please note that this is a working solution for the actual state of the iOS which might be prone to breaking changes in the future.

Answer (score 0):

✅ Following code snippet has worked for me.

```
    static func validateBrowserURL(url: String){
    let safari = XCUIApplication(bundleIdentifier: "com.apple.mobilesafari")
    defer {safari.terminate()}
    let addressBarIpad = safari.buttons["Address"]
    let addressBarIphone = safari.textFields["Address"]
    let addressBarTextField = safari.textFields["Address"]
    
    if app.isIPad {
        addressBarIpad.tapWhenDidAppear(waitSecondsForExistence: 10)
    } else {
        addressBarIphone.tapWhenDidAppear(waitSecondsForExistence: 10)
    }
    
    let urlValue = addressBarTextField.value as! String
    XCTAssertTrue(urlValue.contains(url), "Couldn't locate \(url)")
}
```